# WP Admin Bar Missing

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am very new to making WordPress themes and i have recently started developing my first one. I have got some content working and the home page works now. But when i log into WordPress and view the site there is no Admin bar at the top (as I am used too). I think I have just forgotten something in the one of the files that makes it appear but I am not 100% sure.

I presume this will be applied in the heading so below is my `header.php`

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tutorial theme</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
                <p class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

It is very basic but this is because i am new. I am developing this theme from scratch as a personal Project. If you need any more info just ask and i will update the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your theme needs the basic [plugin API hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Plugin_API_Hooks) that allow WordPress to inject code at various points. For example, the admin bar is inserted when WordPress writes to the footer when you call `wp_footer()`. I think it may also use styles inserted at `wp_head()`.

So, basically, follow the [Theme Documentation Advice](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Plugin_API_Hooks) and add calls to `wp_head()`, `wp_footer()`, `wp_meta()`, and `comment_form()` (if applicable) to your template code in the places it tells you to, and your admin bar should magically appear.

Comment: where abouts do the hooks go in the code, and that's great advice i didn't know about that page!

Comment: This is very clearly spelled out in the documentation. While it's partially up to you, `wp_head()` usually goes in your header, and `wp_footer()` well...in your footer.

Comment: Sorry i was beign a total noob, i did it and it worked, thankyou. if you know any good wp resources for theme development please throw me a link :)

Answer (score 0):

> The toolbar can be turned on/off from the Administration > Users > Your Profile,
> [...]
>
> If you have turned the Toolbar on in your profile settings, but still
> don't see it on the front end of your site, it may be that your theme
> does not call wp_footer() in its footer.php file, or the Toolbar may
> be disabled by a plugin.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Toolbar